# How to find out the number of the adapter, SCSI-ID and LUN (Logical Unit Number) for a USB-DVD-Drive?

Tags: windows, usb, dvd, scsi

I am using a DVD-Drive that is plugged in via USB. I have got a corrupted DVD which I try to recover by using the Tool [h2cdimage](http://www.heise.de/download/h2cdimage.html).

This tool needs the number of the adapter, SCSI-ID and LUN (Logical Unit Number) of my drive to read the DVDs contents.

Where can I find information on these properties?